# Why images can be uploaded with char array but not with equal std::istringstream in C++?

Tags: c++, file-upload, c-strings

Consider the code below for a second:

```
    char buffer[4000];
    size_t bytes = recv(fd, buffer, 4000, 0);
    write(pipefd[1], buffer, bytes);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
```

Here I read fd, write data to the pipe and close the pipe. This allows to eventually upload tiny images that can be rendered. However, if I do everything the same, only replace char array with std::istringstream, as in the example below:

```
    char buffer[4000];
    size_t bytes = recv(fd, buffer, 4000, 0);

    std::istringstream data(buffer);
    write(pipefd[1], data.str().c_str(), bytes);

    close(pipefd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
```

Then image is uploaded but cannot be rendered. (Via pipes this C++ program communicates with a php-cgi script).

Also:

```
if (strcmp(data.str().c_str(), buffer) == 0)
 // returns true
```

I am very curious as to why this could be the case.

Comment: What OS? I guess Windows? Then `\n` in `std::istringstream data` become `\r\n`.

Comment: Can it be so with MacOS, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> std::istringstream data(buffer);
> ```

This assumes `buffer` is a null-terminated string.  Binary data typically contains `0x00` bytes, thus you would end up truncating the `buffer` contents.

Use this instead:

```
std::istringstream data(std::string(buffer, bytes), std::ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run on Windows, then C++ streams add carriage return `\r` before single `\n` automatically while reading and writing. The fix is simple

```
std::istringstream data(buffer, std::ios::binary);
```

MacOS is configurable for using any of `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`. You should never expect what is used and always apply the stream mode `std::ios::binary` for binary data.

However the both code snippets are not valid, `std::istringstream data(buffer)` and `std::string data(buffer)` use bytes in `data` until first zero byte met.

Comment: "*on Windows, then C++ streams add carriage return `\r` after single `\n` automatically*" - you have that backwards.  `\r` goes *before* `\n`, not *after*.